# How to test snippet code in liftweb using specs2 framework

Tags: scala, lift, specs2

I'm trying to write a Specs2 test case that will test the snippets.
 My snippet would look something like this:

```
class RegisterTest extends Specification {
  val testurl = "http:/html/register?username=liftvalues"
  val testSession = MockWeb.testS(testurl) { S.session }
  def inSession[T](a: => T): T = S.initIfUninitted(testSession) { a }
  def is = s2"""   example1 $e1   """
  val html = <form><input name="username" value="liftvalues"></input></form>
  def e1 = {
    inSession{
      register(html)
    }
  }  
  def register(in:NodeSeq):Result = {
      val username = S.param("username") //Here we are getting "Empty Value" for the S object. 
      username === "liftvalues"  and  UserSchemaTest.registerData("data")
  }
}
```

This test fails since `S.param` is `Empty`. What should I do to supply the snippet with a mocked Request?

So far I have looked at [Unit Testing Snippets With A Logged In User](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Unit_Testing_Snippets_With_A_Logged_In_User)
and [Mocking HTTP Requests](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mocking_HTTP_Requests), but I do not understand how to achive my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as-is shouldn't even compile, since among other things `testSession` would return a `Box[LiftSession]` and `S.initIfUninitted` requires an unboxed `LiftSession`. Also, that shouldn't even be needed since `MockWeb.testS` will initialize the session for you, [see here](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/mockweb/MockWeb.scala?source=cc#L183).

I'm not super familiar with Specs2, but I believe something like this should do what you want or at least get you close:

```
class RegisterTest extends Specification {

  val testurl = "http://html/register?username=liftvalues"

  val html = <form><input name="username" value="liftvalues"></input></form>
  def e1 = register(html)  

  def register(in:NodeSeq):Boolean = {
      val username = S.param("username") //Here we are getting "Empty Value" for the S object. 
      username === "liftvalues" and  UserSchemaTest.registerData("data")
  }

  MockWeb.testS(testurl) {
    s2"""   example1 $e1   """
  }

}
```

Everything that gets called from within the `MockWeb.testS` block should have access to your session and request - so you'd be able to make your method calls normally.

Also, your test also looks wrong, a `s2"""` will probably throw an error. But, I'm not entirely sure what you are wanting it to do so I couldn't suggest an alternative.